# Java home seems to be invalid after trying to update jdk, now points only to uninstalled java executable and won't change

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-8, java-11

So last night I sent my code to another developer, who worked on it and sent it back to me today. Since then I got an error saying this program has been accessed from a newer version of Java or something to that effect so I tried to uninstall all of the Java programs on my computer and reinstall the newer version, deleting the 11.0.5 version of Java.

However, even though I have downloaded the newer version of Java and set the path variable and JAVA_HOME (I have checked 3 times but included images anyway) when I /graldew build or run bootRun in IDEA my SpringBootApplication it just comes up with the below error.

```
Gradlew build debug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.5\bin\java.exe
```

[image: Image of path variable]

[image: Image of java home and java program directory]

Comment: Did you check this? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html  You can set the JAVA_HOME for gradle specifically. Maybe you did that previously so it is overriding JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the conflicting entry, `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` taking precedence.

1. Keep clicking `Move Up` button until `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk11.0.12\bin` becomes the top entry.
2. Open a new `cmd` window and execute the command, `java -version` to confirm if the new configuration has taken place.

Comment: The existence of `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` is also an indicator that either, an old Java version is still there, or the uninstall was incomplete. In the latter case, you can remove this entry from the path entirely and even delete this `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java` directory (and `Oracle` as well if there’s nothing else in it).